# remove parent folder but keep content of childs

Tags: bash

I'm trying to organize a bit my music folder. Right now it has many subfolders inside.

Inside every one of those subfolders, there is a subsubfolder with the artist_name which contains music files.

E.g.:

```
Music_folder/silly_name001/artist_A;
Music_folder/silly_name002/artist_B_discA;
Music_folder/silly_name003/artist_B_discB;
```

I can list the content of the Music_ folder and get the names of the subfolders with this:

```
for i in $(ls -d */); do echo ${i%%/}; done
```

But when I try to move the content of those subsubfolders to the parent folder, I can't achieve my goal. I'm using this code:

```
for i in $(ls -d */); do mv ${i%%/*} .; done
```

Actually, it moves the subsubfolders but not the content of them.

Any ideas about how to achieve it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you concerned about name collisions if two subdirectories contain files with the same name?

Comment: @chepner, in this case there will not be collisions, but I would keep that in mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`${i%%/*}` removes the longest prefix matching `/*`; see:

```
$ i=Music_folder/silly_name003/artist_B_discB;
$ echo ${i%%/*}
Music_folder
```

You're looking for something like this:

```
set ./*/
echo mv ./*/* .
echo rmdir "$@"
```

Drop `echo`s if you're happy with the output.

Note that this can't deal with name collisions.

Comment: neat solution! Thanks a lot!